# MYSQL count subquery on current row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, subquery

I am having trouble with this query and am hoping someone can help.

```
  SELECT 
    myTable.id,
    myTable.subject,
    myTable.upvotes,
    myTable.downvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) 
     FROM myTable 
     WHERE myTable.thread = myTable.id) AS comments_count 
  FROM myTable
```

Basically I have a table with posts and comments, the comments thread is tied to the id of the original post. In my query I want to show how many relpies (how many threads = id) from all rows for the current id/row.

I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the the table with new alias to match in your subquery other wise it will match the thread with id from same table

```
SELECT 
m.id,
m.subject,
m.upvotes,
m.downvotes,
(SELECT COUNT(id) 
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE myTable.thread = m.id) AS comments_count 
FROM myTable m
```

Or Better to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    m.id,
    m.subject,
    m.upvotes,
    m.downvotes,
    COUNT(mm.id) AS comments_count 
FROM myTable m 
  LEFT JOIN  myTable mm ON(mm.thread = m.id)
 GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes perfect sense. I should have used an alias. I will try the left join as well. Thanks again!!